How can I use !important on inline styles in an email?
I send out a newsletter for my university, using Mailchimp. There are no known issues with delivery into Outlook mailboxes, but if you try to forward the newsletter through Outlook, Outlook overrides the newsletter HTML with its own HTML preferences and forwards something illegible.
how newsletter looks when forwarded from Outlook -- bad

how newsletter looks when it arrives in outlook mailbox -- good

I read to add !important into the Mailchimp HTML code so that Outlook will not change the formatting, but I don't know where to put it.
Here is some of the code:
    <span style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span 
    style="font-size: 17px"><span style="font-family: 
    'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 
    'Lucida Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif">I hope this message 
    finds you well and that your academic year is off to a 
    good start.&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span></span></p>
    <p><span style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span 
    style="font-size: 17px"><span style="font-family: 
    'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 
    'Lucida Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif">&nbsp;</span></span> 
    </span></p>
    <p><span style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span 
    style="font-size: 17px">

I have heard to try putting !important; into the HTML code around the style features of the newsletter-- ie. background color, text color, font, etc. But I have not tried it because I don't know where to put it in the code.

A helpfull tool for email design is Can i email?.
You can check if the styling is supported on different email clients.

For example rgb() is just partialy supported in outlook, which may causes the problem. How did you set your background-color for those blocks?
I know th question is about !important, but this may be a helpfull tipp.

Have you looked closely at the forwarded code to see exactly which of your settings are being overridden?

Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Couple of questions. 1) Can you share the full code? What's happening is that Outlook is re-rendering your code, due to the way emails work. (2) Is there a particular inbox (e.g. Gmail) that you need the forward to work for, or is it mostly Outlook to Outlook? (3) Is it only happening on dark mode?

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important.
In short, use it immediately prior to any semicolon in the style attribute values to place precedence on that particular rule. It cannot be applied globally or to groups of rules.
Note that your style rules don't always have optional trailing semicolons, so you'd use !important right before the closing quotation mark, as:
style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', ..., sans-serif !important"


Thank you! I added this into the code, but Mailchimp seemed to automatically erase it. The code reverted back to how it had been before I put in !important. I don't know how to get the edited code to stay in place...

I can't find anything to indicate that Mailchimp strips !important. I wonder if your syntax was ok. Also, inline styles have a high precedence to begin with, so I'm doubtful that you even need this solution.
